# How to design tables to be side by side

Tags: tables

I have the following LaTeX code for two tables:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       \textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Customer Engagement Average}   \\ \hline
     Apple & 1,937,852.45  \\ 
     Huawei & 156,962.065  \\ 
     Samsung & 174,166.98  \\ 
      
         \end{tabular}
    \caption{Average Brand Customer Engagement}
    \label{brand_ce}
%\end{table}

%\begin{table}[h]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       \textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Customer Satisfaction Score Average}   \\ \hline
     Apple & 3.37  \\ 
     Huawei & 4.049  \\ 
     Samsung & 3.76  \\ 
      
         \end{tabular}
    \caption{Average Brand Customer Satisfaction Score}
    \label{brand_sscore}
\end{table}
```

Those tables are on top of each other as the following figure:

[image]

I need to to put those tables side by side.

Comment: Remove the empty line in between them (that starts a new paragraph). Also, to get the captions at the correct position use `minipage` inside the `table` environment, like this: `\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\centering\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\caption{...}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}...\end{minipage}`. You can play with the `0.5\linewidth` to get something more pleasing.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz I've tried your answer and it works, thanks and I appreciate

Comment: Why not combine the information into a single table? You can then avoid repeating the first column.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `floatrow` and the `S` column type for the second column, to align numbers on the decimal dot. Note that traditionally, tables have their captions *above* tables, which is done automatically by float row. Furthermore, loading `geometry`, you'll have more sensible margins (this supposes you don't need marginal notes).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{caption, floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, group-separator={,}}
\captionsetup{format=hang, justification=raggedright}
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox{\caption{Average Brand Customer Engagement} \label{brand_ce}}%
    {\centering\begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format=7.3]}
       \textbf{Brand} & {\thead{Customer Engagement\\ Average}} \\ \hline
     Apple & 1937852.45 \\
     Huawei & 156962.065 \\
     Samsung & 174166.98
         \end{tabular}}
\qquad
   \ttabbox{\caption{Average Brand Customer Satisfaction Score} \label{brand_sscore}}%
   {\begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format=1.3]}
       \thead[b]{Brand} & {\thead{Customer Satisfaction\\ Score Average}} \\ \hline
     Apple & 3.37 \\
     Huawei & 4.049 \\
     Samsung & 3.76
      \end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
        \textbf{Brand} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Customer Average}}  \\ 
        &\textbf{-Engagement-} &\textbf{-Satisfaction Score-}\\\hline
        Apple & 1,937,852.45& 3.37   \\ 
        Huawei & 156,962.065  & 4.049  \\ 
        Samsung & 174,166.98& 3.76  \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Average Brand Customer Engagement}
    \label{brand_ce}

\end{table}
```